# How to make @root_validator in Pydantic return model class object rather than values?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am currently using a root_validator in my FastAPI project using Pydantic like this:

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[int]
    name: Optional[str]

    @root_validator
    def validate(cls, values):
        if not values.get("id") and not values.get("name"):
            raise ValueError("It's an error")
        return values
```

The issue is, when I query the request body in FastAPI, because of `return values`, instead of the request body being of type `class User`, it is just a simple python dictionary. How do I get the same object of type `class User`?

So initially, my request body would like this when I printed it: `id=0 name='string'` (which is how I want it) (and when I print the `type()` of it, it shows: `<class 'User'>`)

Here is what it looks like with `return values`: `{"id":0, "name"="string"}`

I have tried making it as just `return cls`, but this is what it looks like when I print it: `<class 'User'>` (and when I print the `type()` of it, it shows: `<class 'pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass'>`)

How to get my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had raised this issue in FastAPI and Pydantic discussions. And found the answer here by a community member: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/4563

The solution is to rename the `def validate` func to anything else like `def validate_all_fields`

And the reason for this is `validate` is base method for `BaseModel` in Pydantic!!

Comment: Oh, man! thanks a lot for your help! I had the same problem and I couldn't imagine about this solution!!